# jQuery TextExt Plugin: add tag after keypress "space" and click on some button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have one input

```
<input type="text" style="width:200px" id="myInputTags" placeholder="add tag" />
<input type="button" id="btnId" />
```

in script

```
jQuery("#myInputTags").textext({ plugins: 'tags' });
```

now when I press enter in this input the tag is created, but I want to added this tags after click on my button and after keypress "space" 
some proposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hi.**

```
jQuery("#myInputTags")
    .textext({
        plugins: 'tags, prompt', 
        prompt: 'add tag'
    })
   .keypress(function(event){
     //'Space' key is pressed in keyboard
     if(event.which==32){
       addTag();
     }
   });

jQuery("#btnId").click(function(){
    addTag();
})

function addTag(){
    //Take the value from text input
    var tag = $('#myInputTags').val();

    //Clear the text input and add tag
    $('#myInputTags').val('').textext()[0]
    .tags().addTags([tag]);
}
```

[See a Live Demo of this](http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/r6gar2c3/11/)

**Docs:** [TexExt - Adding Tags Directly](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html)